# Generating Combinatorics With Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, combinations

I am trying to implement a quick tool to find the combinations of a set of numbers `(0...k)`, for `j` lots of this array, where the sum across the row is equal to `k-j`, and `k>=j`

For instance, for k=3, and j=2, I have all the following combinations:

```
[[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [0 2]
 [1 0]
 [1 1]
 [1 2]
 [2 0]
 [2 1]
 [2 2]]
```

There are only two elements that sum up to `k-j=1`:

```
[[0 1]
[1 0]]
```

My current implementation is slow as I approach high numbers of k and j:

```
        from itertools import product
        from numpy import 
        combs = np.array(list(product(np.arange(0, k), repeat=j)))
        combs = combs[np.sum(combs, axis=1)==k-j]
        print(combs)
```

Can anyone please suggest a more efficient algorithm than I have at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you don't have to consider the range up to `k`, but only up to `k-j`. Further, you could use `itertools.combinations` (if you are only interested in the set and not the order), as follows:

```
combs = np.array(list(combinations(range(k-j+1), j)))
combs = combs[np.sum(combs, axis=1)==k-j]
```